# Varying Non-Linear Parameters Based on Groups in R

Tags: r, categorical-data, nonlinear-regression

I'm trying to develop a non-linear model, but I'd like to have the values for the parameters vary by group. To give you an example, a section of my data (just random numbers here) looks like:

```
  MONTH FUTURE.PC FUTURE.SALES
1   APR        35         1498
2   APR        22         1124
3   MAY        24          744
4   MAY        45          453
5   MAY        13         1024  
6   JUN        26          689
```

Say I wanted to make a non-linear model that looked like

```
nls(FUTURE.SALES ~ a + b * FUTURE.PC ^ c)
```

Is there a way to change the values of $a$, $b$, and $c$ based on which month the record belongs to? Alternatively, is there a way to incorporate factor variables in non-linear regression in $R$?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to change the values of a, b, and c based on which month the record belongs to?

Sure, there are a variety of ways, depending on your model for how they change.

> is there a way to incorporate factor variables in non-linear regression in R?

Certainly. Here's an example of one way (there may be better ways):

```
 x=10:30
 xe=exp((x-18)/3)
 y=50*xe/(1+xe)+rnorm(21)
 plot(x,y)

 b=rep(1:3,times=7)   # these value will be used for my factor variable
 bf=model.matrix(~as.factor(b)) # get the dummies

nls(y~a*exp(b0+b1*x)/(1+exp(b0+b1*x))+b2*bf[,2]+b3*bf[,3],
      start=list(a=52,b0=-5,b1=.3,b2=-.2,b3=-.1))
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ a * exp(b0 + b1*x)/(1 + exp(b0 + b1*x)) + b2 * bf[,2] + b3 * bf[,3]
   data: parent.frame()
      a      b0      b1      b2      b3 
50.4555 -5.8314  0.3245 -0.3729 -0.2740 
 residual sum-of-squares: 18.83

Number of iterations to convergence: 4 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 9.468e-06
```

---

In either case, take care, however, with trying to use `nls` with many parameters.